# error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following this tutorial:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

At the "`node query.js`" command I received the following error:

    `Create a client and set the wallet location
    Set wallet path, and associate user  PeerAdmin  with application
    Check user is enrolled, and set a query URL in the network
    Make query
    Assigning transaction_id:  f7d1d9b40c37bb21909bdb6ff24980da33758fb1ea5a85cb67d699f3fcd3ffa2
    error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown
        at /home/user/work/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17
    returned from query
    Query result count =  1
    error from query =  { [Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown] code: 2, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
    Response is  Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That error seems to be an error corresponding to the configuration of the channel of the Blockchain. Have you followed all the steps of the manual?

Comment: Yes! I think is a bug: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5154

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: I have the same issue when kafka cluster was added. My docker version is 17.09.0-ce

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem as yourself.

My solution:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove docker-ce
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

Will only work on docker v1.13+/17.03.  Found from [source1](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5154) and [source2](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/11849/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with docker. When I had the same problem, I fixed it by updating docker with the commands below:

```html
sudo apt-get --purge remove docker-ce
sudo apt-get remove docker
sudo apt-get remove  docker-ce

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

sudo apt-get install docker-ce
docker -v
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose -v

sudo reboot
```

Once docker has been updated, try again and see if the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your Docker Version. There is [a bug report in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0.0](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5154) that has been corrected in version 1.0.1 that looks like the situation you described.

The recommended solution is to upgrade Docker version to **17.03.0-ce  or later** and upgrade your Hyperledger Fabric version to **1.0.1 or later**.

Comment: One question here. If I use docker images for fabric peers and other network artefacts, which one is 1.0.1? How to reference it?